# Error: Cannot find module 'connect-multiparty'

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

I want to use middleware to get `req.files`. I have `connect-multiparty` module already installed in `express`. When i try to import it throws me error.

routes.js

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, practices.editLogo);
```

error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'connect-multiparty'
```

---

on npm install i get following :-

```
npm WARN package.json myproject@2.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json myproject@2.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json myproject@2.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json papercut@0.0.6 No repository field.
```

I am following this :-

https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty

Comment: where did you install `connect-multiparty`? please paste a full path to it and to `routes.js`

Comment: ohh..sorry....In fact...`connect-multiparty` module is not present in `express` folder in `node-modules`.

Comment: The warnings are just that--warnings. They will not affect your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you've installed this module in wrong folder. Go to folder containing `routes.js` and run `npm install connect-multiparty`. So that folder should contain `node_modules` folder which contains this module

[Here is a documentation of how `require` works](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

Comment: With `npm` it matters in which folder exactly you're running `npm install ...`. So if you are for example in `/home/username` folder, npm will create `/home/username/node_modules` folder and put this module there

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you have it installed properly. Are you sure you did `npm install` since you added this code?

edit - I see you just copied the code from `connect-multiparty`'s page, so yeah. Should work.

Comment: i did `npm update` by adding in `package.json` "connect-multiparty":"2.2.0"

Comment: `npm update` doesn't install new packages. you need to `npm install`